# Bootstrap, no background after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/
I wanted to change this white background, but when I generate some data and scroll page, it is under it still white.

[image]

I've changed in this bootstrap only this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;

}

#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
```

Comment: You are limiting the height of the relevant elements to 100% of the viewport height here – so all content that goes beyond that, flows out if its container element, it does not increase its height beyond those 100% – and that’s why you are seeing a white background, because this part is outside of the element that you specified a red background for. Use `min-height:100%` on the wrapper instead. (Or `min-height:100vh` – then you don’t need to set `height:100%` for `html` and `body` any more, which can lead to more complications with scrolling behavior etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you now just have

`body { background-color: red; }`

or with a gradient you could do:-

`#wrapper {
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Standard syntax */
    height: 100vh;
}`

Comment: If I add this to body and wrapper is works. But it is separate. And I wanted gradient in background. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Is any fast way to use one one of gradient? For example one od this: http://codepen.io/taylorvowell/pen/BkxbC

Comment: you wanting vertical gradient?

Comment: Doesn't matter, but smooth. But if there isn't simple way, I will left just one color :)

Comment: Updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#wrapper {
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
background: red;
}
```

Comment: @user3797879 so try the answer above which it's `body { background: red; }`